# How to Make Info Boxes Appear on Website on Click

Tags: javascript, html, css, popupwindow

On certain websites, when a link such as "read more" is clicked, a popup box will appear, and the behind webpage will often darken. The popup box then contains information and can be closed by clicking a button in the corner.

I'd like to make several of them. Would I do so simply by creating a div and pehaps another one with a transparency to "darken" the webpage behind the popup or is there a code I could use in javascript?

Comment: I would check out jQuery-ui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally people here are suggesting `lightboxes`, which work wonderfully for galleries, but are **complete overkill** for info boxes like this.  Lightboxes can slow your website down alot, as they require a lot of assets to be included, multiple HTTP requests for `.css` files and `.js` files, when your problem could be solved via CSS and JS.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3vmL6/1/

In your code you have a a simple `div` of a class `modal-dialog`, which is automatically hidden in the css (see the fiddle).

```
<div id="info-modal" class="modal-dialog">
<div>
  <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">x</a>
  <h2>Hello!</h2>
  <p>You can display any information you want here!</p>
</div>
```

A simple snippet of JQuery in your document is used to call a specific instance of the modal-dialog, allowing you to have multiple unique `div`s using different ID's, but all belonging to the same class.

```
$("#click-me").click(function () {

$.ajax({
    success: function (data) {                               
        console.log(data);   
        $('#info-modal').addClass("show"); 
    },
    async: true
    });    
});

$(".modal-dialog .close").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".modal-dialog").removeClass("show"); 
});
```

Comment: everything works perfectly, except when the popup appears, it scrolls me back up to the top of the page instead of the popup overlapping the current section of the page. How can I fix that?

Comment: @etangins sorry for the late reply! Instead of `<a href="#" id="click-me">`, you need to get rid of the `href` entirely. This would remove the little hand you get for the link, so in the CSS for your `<a>`, you need to add `cursor:pointer`.  See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NM9aZ/1/

Comment: @etangins this does mean that existing defaults on `a:link` etc will not be triggered as your `<a>` no longer has the `href` attribute. Most browsers interpret this to mean the `<a>` is not a hyperlink, however that won't stop JQuery's `click()` functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing it yourself, you'd put an overlay over the entire page and give it a high z-index so that it will cover all of your dom elements.  Then have a div, with a higher z-index positioned where you need it to be with the content you want.

An easier approach is to use a library that already has that functionality baked in

jQuery UI dialog - http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

bootstrap modal - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are looking for: http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a lightbox/modal box. I recommand [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) because it works with responsive design, but [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) is also very good.

Answer (score 2):

You essentially are looking to work with modals so. Zurb provide a library to do just this for you in foundation. The library is called reveal. It's simple to use. I use it a good bit. You can see it here. Hope that helps.

http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

Answer (score 2):

This code should do what your asking for

```
window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("member").onclick = function(){
        var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        popup.style.display = "block";
            };
<div id="overlay">
</div>
<div id="popup">
your readme text in here 
</div>
#overlay
{
display:none;    
position:fixed; 
left:0px;       
top:0px;         
width:100%;      
height:100%;     
background:#000; 
opacity:0.5;     
z-index:99999;
}
#popup
{
display:none;
position:fixed;
left:40%;           
top:40%;             
width:600px;         
height:500px;
margin-top:-75px;   
margin-left:-150px;  
background:#FFFFFF;  
border:2px solid #000;  
z-index:100000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

they are called modals or dialogs, there are several frameworks that will help you in this case.

one of the most popular is bootstrap

http://getbootstrap.com/